# Validate that resource exists before retrieving keys

Tags: c#, azure, pulumi

I create a resource group, and a database account:

```
// Create resourceGroup:
var rg= new ResourceGroup("myRG",
            new ResourceGroupArgs
            {
                Name = "myRG",
                Location = "westeurope"
            });
// Create DBAccount:
var account = new DatabaseAccount(accountName, new Pulumi.AzureNextGen.DocumentDB.Latest.DatabaseAccountArgs
            {
                AccountName = "myAcc",
                DatabaseAccountOfferType = DatabaseAccountOfferType.Standard,
                Location = "WestEurope",
                ResourceGroupName = rg.GetResourceName()
            });
```

After I did this I want to retrieve the primary key:

```
var keys = ListDatabaseAccountKeys.InvokeAsync(new ListDatabaseAccountKeysArgs
{
  AccountName = account.GetResourceName(),
  ResourceGroupName = rg.GetResourceName()
});
var cosmosWriteKey = Output.Create(keys).Apply(q => q.PrimaryMasterKey);
```

On the first start on a blank subscription without any resourcegroup with "pulumi up" I receive an error

> Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="ResourceGroupNotFound" Message="Resource group 'myRG' could not be found.

I currently solved this by setting an environment variable disabling the "Key"-Part on the first run and run the code again after the ResourceGroup is created. But maybe there is a more smart way to assure the resourcegroup is created before retrieving the keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should link the account to the resource group by using `rg.Name` in its constructor and put your `ListDatabaseAccountKeys` invocation inside an `Apply`:

```cs
var account = new DatabaseAccount(accountName, new DatabaseAccountArgs
{
    AccountName = "myAcc",
    DatabaseAccountOfferType = DatabaseAccountOfferType.Standard,
    Location = "WestEurope",
    ResourceGroupName = rg.Name
});

var cosmosWriteKey = account.Name.Apply(async name =>
{
    var keys = await ListDatabaseAccountKeys.InvokeAsync(new ListDatabaseAccountKeysArgs
    {
        AccountName = name,
        ResourceGroupName = "myRG"
    });
    return keys.PrimaryMasterKey;
});
```

This way, the invocation will only happen after the account is created and the `Name` output is resolved.

If you migrate to [Azure-Native](https://www.pulumi.com/blog/full-coverage-of-azure-resources-with-azure-native/), you can use auto-naming:

```cs
var rg = new ResourceGroup("myRG");

var account = new DatabaseAccount(accountName, new DatabaseAccountArgs
{
    DatabaseAccountOfferType = DatabaseAccountOfferType.Standard,
    ResourceGroupName = rg.Name
});

var cosmosWriteKey = Output.Tuple(rg.Name, account.Name).Apply(async values =>
{
    var keys = await ListDatabaseAccountKeys.InvokeAsync(new ListDatabaseAccountKeysArgs
    {
        ResourceGroupName = values[0],
        AccountName = values[1]
    });
    return keys.PrimaryMasterKey;
});
```

Comment: I might have oversimplified my example for SO, sorry. I already used GetResourceName() to retrieve the names in the realworld-example. Updated my question

Comment: That doesn't change anything. You shouldn't use `GetResourceName()` for that: it retrieves the logical name and doesn't wait for resource creation.